# Push Notification always Start Main Activity Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I have 3 Activities in my Android application:

```
1. Main
2. Welcome
3. Articles
```

The life cycle of app starts from Main -> Welcome -> Article. I have implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) in my application, through which I want to start either Welcome or Articles activity. The code goes like this:

```
private void createNote(String title, String body, String key) {
        try {
            Intent screen;
            int code = key == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(key);
            if (key == null) {
                screen = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
            } else {
                screen = new Intent(this, Articles.class);
                screen.putExtra("key", key);
                screen.putExtra("name", title);
            }
            screen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            screen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, screen, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            //
            NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setTicker(title + " has new Item")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentIntent(intent)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(code, notification.build());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG + "NOTE", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**The Application Block from Manifest File**

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name=".infotropy.Main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".infotropy.Welcome"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
        <activity android:name=".infotropy.Articles" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
```

My problem is that no matter which Activity Class Reference screen variable hold, after clicking Push Notification, always **Main Activity** got started, which I have even not mentioned anywhere in the said function.

The code should start either **Welcome** or **Articles** activity, but it always activate **Main**. Please give a solution.

**Edit :**

As asked, I am sharing the the Class code to handle FCM Push Notification:

```
public class Notify extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private final String TAG = "NOTIFY_";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        try {
            String key = null;
            Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            Log.d(TAG, "From : " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
            Log.d(TAG, "Body : " + body);
            if (data.containsKey("key")) {
                key = data.get("key").toString();
            }
            createNote(title, body, key);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG + "RECEIVER", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void createNote(String title, String body, String key) {
        try {
            Intent screen;
            int code = key == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(key);
            if (key == null) {
                screen = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
            } else {
                screen = new Intent(this, Articles.class);
                screen.putExtra("key", key);
                screen.putExtra("name", title);
            }
            screen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            screen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//            Intent welcome = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
//            welcome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, screen,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            //
            NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setTicker(title + " has new Item")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentIntent(intent)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(code, notification.build());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG + "NOTE", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @VihangaYasith. Because Articles Activity has the mechanism to Sync latest data from the server. So whenever a push notification appear to refer Articles, all old activities should clear out and Articles will have a new instance to sync latest data from server

Comment: Share your full code of FCM Message Handler.

Comment: @AGMTazim. I have added the full code. Please have a look

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_logo)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Not working. Still same problem. Main Activity is launching besides of Welcome or Articles